# Not able to set number in Restrictions.ilike("id" ,"+"searchTerm"+") in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a Student class with attribute Name and ID as property.

```
Name   || ID

Rahul11   101
Sam       110
```

I make one search bar in which if i search for 11 then it would display all thing that start with 11 in Student Class.

How to achieve it by criteria.add(Restrictions.****)

*Edit: I am using search Term as string*

Comment: i using search Term as string

Comment: Use Enum MatchMode - Restrictions.like("id", "11", MatchMode.END); and if you want case-insensitive results use ilike

Comment: Did you try look for something like this? https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/

Comment: (Restrictions.like("id","11",MatchMode.ANYWHERE).....Still getting error java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer because hibernate trying to covert class  Student  interger property ID to String ...
Any other way to archive it .